# Kendall's W with R?

Tags: r

I would have liked to know how to compute the Kendall rank correlation coefficient with R
and the Kendall's W, also known as Kendall's coefficient of concordance with R.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about how to do something in R, & not any of the related statistical issues.

Comment: @gung Formulas would be on-topic.  Formulas plus examples in `R` (or some other language) would also be on-topic.  Varin, if *all* you want is `R` code to do these computations, then please flag this question for migration to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @whuber, my understanding from the ongoing meta discussion about off-topic threads & SO migration (which I didn't really get before) is that 'how to run test x in `R`' is not considered *programming* / on-topic for SO. As such, if we decide it's off-topic here, it would best be answered via (a) Googling, (b) utilizing our web-based `R` [resources](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info), or perhaps (c) asking on the r-help listserve.

Answer (score 11):

For the correlation, just add the `method` to the `cor` function:

```
cor(data, method = 'kendall')
```

For W there is the `kendall` function in the `irr` package. So,

```
install.packages("irr")
library(irr)
kendall(ratings, correct = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you lots for your answer. And what about the p-value for the kendall ? What is the R code for the p-value ?

Comment: for cor() and the **Kendall package** description, **summary.Kendall** should give the p-vlalue and from the **irr package** description **$p.value** is returned from the list...